# Type families: top level vs. associated

Tags: haskell, types

I am just starting to learn type families.  The GHC documentation states that top level and associated type families have the same functionality, but the code I am writing behaves differently in top level than it does when the families are associated.  This compiles and runs fine:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
module Test where

-- type family R a
-- type instance R Maybe = Int

class C' a where
  type R a
  getInt' :: a Int
  getBool' :: R a -> a Bool

instance C' Maybe where
  type R Maybe = Int
  getInt' = Just 3
  getBool' i = Just $ i < 10

printer :: IO ()
printer = print $ (getBool' 5 :: Maybe Bool)
```

but this gives me a type error:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
module Test where

type family R a
type instance R Maybe = Int

class C' a where
  -- type R a
  getInt' :: a Int
  getBool' :: R a -> a Bool

instance C' Maybe where
  -- type R Maybe = Int
  getInt' = Just 3
  getBool' i = Just $ i < 10

printer :: IO ()
printer = print $ (getBool' 5 :: Maybe Bool)
```

These look identical to me; why is it that one compiles and the other doesn't?

Comment: An associated type family is only different in that the compiler expects 1 or more type instances in every class instance. When the docs says "the same functionality", it means that the semantics are identical for the same declarations, but you still have to place declarations in the correct place. The purpose of "associating" the type family is to remind implementers that they must define that type instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second one works if you annotate the kind:

```
type family R (a :: * -> *)
```

I don't think there's any reason why the right kind is only inferred for the associated type family.

Comment: The right kind is inferred for the associated type family because it has the additional type information present in the functions which use the type family, and the type `a` from the class declaration. For example it sees `a Int` must be a valid type of kind `*`, from which you can infer that `a :: * -> *`. If the type family is not associated, the compiler will obviously not have access to that information, so it gives the type family the default type: `* -> *`.

Comment: I don't agree with _the compiler will obviously not have access to that information_. It seems to be available in that file, it's just not used for whatever reason (nobody asked for it, it's too hard to implement, it would be too confusing to have uses of a type family help determine kinds etc.)

Comment: I agree that it isn't *impossible* in any sense. I meant more along the lines of, the compiler doesn't look at the type families' use sites to determine its type; it probably wouldn't really make sense to do that, especially since the solution is so simple.